# How to order Youtube videos by rating?

Tags: youtube

I've got a problem by using the API: [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it)

I would like to order my results by rating. Therefore, I set the "order" parameter's value to "rating". 
As returned result, I just receive videos with low likes and/or dislikes and it is not ordered by rating. 
Even when I just try it in the API Explorer I get the same results, so it can't be because of my code.

Is there a problem with the API or do I understand the value "rating" wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The V3 API returns the same results you'd get by performing a search on the YouTube site and setting the 'Sort by' filter to Rating eg.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/?q=stackoverflow&order=rating&part=snippet
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_sort=video_avg_rating&search_query=stackoverflow
```

The key point is that it's an average rating, not based only on likes.

The API defines [getRating](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating) as -

> Retrieves the ratings that the authorized user gave to a list of specified videos.

so it would seem the average takes into account likes and dislikes. It's not immediately clear whether the 1-5 rating system (from YouTube V2 API) or any other data is also used?

If you just wish to obtain the `like` count, you can make another API request with your video ID's that returns separate counts for `like`, `dislike`, `none` and `unspecified` -

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/getRating?id=XXXXXXX,XXXXXXX
```