# unable to get top 10 videos of my youtube channel according to likes through youtube api

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

What i am trying is, to get top 10 videos of my Youtube channel based on likes using analytics api v1.

To get based on **views**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2005-05-01&end-date=2014-06-30&metrics=estimatedMinutesWatched%2Cviews%2Clikes%2Cshares&dimensions=video&max-results=10&sort=-views&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

this end point is used where **sort=-views** is the sorting factor.

I am doing the same way to sort based on likes **sort=-likes**

But I am getting error response

```
400 Bad Request


- Show headers -


{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."
 }
}
```

By hit and trial i came to know the **sort=-views and sort=-estimatedMinutesWatched** are working but others i.e. likes,comments etc are not working. What is the possible reason? Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your sort parameter based on the supported parameters from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#top-videos-reports).

So far, these are the supported filters:

> - views
> - redViews
> - estimatedRevenue
> - estimatedRedPartnerRevenue
> - estimatedMinutesWatched
> - estimatedRedMinutesWatched
> - subscribersGained
> - subscribersLost

Also if this could help, I think you can try [Videos: getRating](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating).

> Retrieves the ratings that the authorized user gave to a list of
>   specified videos.

But this method is basing on the ratings not the actual likes, but one of the following:

> - dislike
> - like
> - none
> - unspecified

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476217/how-to-order-youtube-videos-by-rating) for further reference.

Comment: i guess Estimated revenue and ad performance metrics are not currently supported for channel reports.